# Why do 3 x 33% width columns not fit in a 100% container

Tags: css

This issue has been irking me for some time now. PLEASE somebody solve me this code riddle without changing the column widths from equaling EXACTLY 100%.

```
<style>
/* slider style rules */
  * {
     padding: 0; margin: 0;  
    }
  .slider ul {
     list-style: none; 
   }
 .slider ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%; 
        /* ^= set this to 32% and watch the horizontal adjustment
        of the items if your   confused   */
    }
   </style>

   <div class="slider">
      <h2>Why do 3 x 33% width columns not fit in a 100% container?</h2>
        <span>Shouldn't there be an <em>EXTRA</em>1%? if each column is 33% x 3 columns = 99%    why with every single elements padding and margin reset do the elements not fit in the page</span>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

[Heres the fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/vZffU/)

Comment: Don't know why, something to do with a block level item maybe. to make it work just float left.

Comment: I'm using 27" monitor and everything is ok. But when I move it to 15.4" monitor it does not fit.

Comment: interesting find here. http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block apparently inline-block items take white space into account. weird.

Comment: It's the box model.  Width in calculated as the with of the contents not including padding, border,  and margin.

Comment: @agconti he doesn't have padding margin or border, it's the white space between the inline-block elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a working snippet:

```css
/* slider style rules */

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.slider ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.slider ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;  /*demo purposes */
  box-sizing: border-box; /*demo purposes */
  width: 33%;  /*<= set this to 32% and watch the horizontal adjustment of the items if your confused */
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <h2>Why do 3 x 33% width columns not fit in a 100% container?</h2>
  <span>Shouldnt there be an <em>EXTRA</em> 1%? if each column is 33%x3coluns = 99% why with every single elements padding and margin reset do these els not fit in the page</span>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li><li>Item</li><li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the problem is the `li` having `display:inline-block` which create gaps, so you on way is to remove unnecessary gaps between `li` in your HMTL  (the solution I used on this fiddle)

check other solutions here:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/