# CSS - 25% width on list element

Tags: css

This is super simple but my brain wont work and I cant work it out.

I have a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/krt9f8h1/

I have 4 list elements that are floated left in a line.

I have width 25% on the elements to space them evenly on one line.

Why doesn't this work.

```
    <div class="block">
      <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: what's the problem? your code is working how you told him to do, explain your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do 3 x 33% width columns not fit in a 100% container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572802/why-do-3-x-33-width-columns-not-fit-in-a-100-container)

Answer (score 4):

That is because:

1. Padding is added on top of the width when `box-sizing` is set to content-box. So when you have four list items, their summed widths are actually 25% + 10px (left) and 10px (right). This exceeds 100%, causing the last item to wrap to the next line.
2. When using `display: inline-block`, all white space are treated as such. So each line break between each list element adds additional horizontal whitespace. You can use `<!--...-->` to comment out the whitespace between each, but I generally recommend using floats or flexbox instead of trying to use this slightly dirty hack:

   ```
   <div class="block">
     <ul>
       <li>One</li><!--
       --><li>Two</li><!--
       --><li>Three</li><!--
       --><li>Four</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   ```

Solution:

1. For excess width, use one of the following:

   - `box-sizing: border-box` to force the width to take into include paddings (**recommended**)
   - `width: calc(25% - 20px)` to subtract padding (but you have to update this calculation when you change your paddings)
2. For horizontal positioning of list items, use one of the following for list items:

   - [CSS3 flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox&search=flex) (**recommended** because it's the simplest and the most flexible) or
   - float (remember to use `overflow: hidden` on parent to prevent dimension collapse)
   - inline-block with commented out whitespaces (I highly do not recommend this)

Proof-of-concept examples:

## 1. Using CSS3 flexbox

In this example, float the list items and declare `overflow: hidden` to stop the parent from collapsing.

```css
.block{
  background: gray;  
  //padding: 10px;
}

ul{
  overflow: hidden; /* Prevent parent collapse due to floated children */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  float: left;      /* Float list items */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## 2. Using float

In this example, use CSS3 flexbox specification. We do not need to worry about the parent collapsing in this case.

```css
.block{
  background: gray;  
  //padding: 10px;
}

ul{
  display: flex;  /* One-liner solution ;) */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is you working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krt9f8h1/1/)

Problem is that display: inline-block still has some gaps between. You neeed to use `float: left; display: block` instead. Also you need to add clearfix for ul

The last part is that you need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` for elements to be sure that their width is including padding

```
ul:after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to calculate the right width for each li element, which is 25% - 10px right padding - 10px left padding - border, then you will have the desired result. This line will solve your problem: width: `calc(25% - 24px);`
Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krt9f8h1/2/)

```css
.block{
  background: gray;  
  //padding: 10px;
}

ul{
  list-style: none:
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li{
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(25% - 24px);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```